# PdfpTable nested in PdfpTable cell has white space on both sides

Tags: c#, itext, pdfptable

I have a main PdfpTable with one column I use as the parent table. I then add tables created with a dynamic # of columns to the parent table.

So each table is a row in the parent table. 
I'm getting what I desired except for a few things:

1) The tables are added with significant white space on both the left and right; I want the sub tables to fill the row space.

2) Column widths aren't holding. The first column of each new table changes width based on the number of total columns it has.

3) The main table width doesn't seem affected by the .TotalWidth setting

```
 PdfPTable mainTable = new PdfPTable(1);
    mainTable.TotalWidth = 1000f;

        //Iterating through some data, get the count then create tables.
        PdfPTable subTable = new PdfPTable(colCount);

//I tried setting the widths to fix issue 2
    float[] colWidths = new float[colCount];
                        colWidths[0] = 50f;
                        for (int i = 1; i < colCount; i++)
                        {
                            colWidths[i] = 50f;
                        }
                        subTable.SetWidths(colWidths);

        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
                                cell.AddElement("test");
                                subTable.AddCell(cell);

         PdfPCell tblCell = new PdfPCell();
                            //tblCell.Padding = 0f;
                            //tblCell.PaddingLeft = 0f;
                            //tblCell.PaddingRight = 0f;
                            tblCell.AddElement(subTable);
                            mainTable.AddCell(tblCell);
```

I've tried setting the widths for each column, remove padding, and set the total widths for both the parent and sub tables but with mixed results.

Comment: I don't have time for a full answer but one point of confusion is that `SetWidths()` set's the _relative_ widths of columns. So if you pass "50, 100" you are _not_ passing 50 units and 100 units but instead saying that the first column should get one third `(50/(50+100))` and the second should get two thirds `(100/(50+100))`. Instead you probably want to use `SetTotalWidth(float[])` along with `LockedWidth`

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to nest tables, each different approach has its own specific behavior. I've demonstrated this in the [NestedTables6](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/tables/nested-tables#1833-nestedtables6.java) example:

First we create the main table:

```
PdfPTable mainTable = new PdfPTable(1);
mainTable.setTotalWidth(1000);
mainTable.setLockedWidth(true);
```

As we define a total width, we also have to lock the width. My code is in Java, but it's very easy to adapt the code to C#. It's something like `mainTable.LockedWidth = true;` (I'm not that proficient in C#, so you'll have to forgive me if my C# isn't entirely correct).

The easiest way to nest a table is to just add the table with `addCell()`. However: in this case, the default padding is used, which means you have to set the default padding to `0`. In C#, that would be something like: `mainTable.DefaultCell.Padding = 0;` In Java, it's done like this:

```
mainTable.getDefaultCell().setPadding(0);
PdfPTable subTable1 = new PdfPTable(5);
subTable1.setTotalWidth(new float[]{200, 200, 200, 100, 300});
subTable1.setLockedWidth(true);
subTable1.addCell("test 1");
subTable1.addCell("test 2");
subTable1.addCell("test 3");
subTable1.addCell("test 4");
subTable1.addCell("test 5");
mainTable.addCell(subTable1);
```

A second way to nest a table, is to create a `PdfPCell` with the table as parameter. In this case, the default padding is `0`.

```
PdfPTable subTable2 = new PdfPTable(5);
subTable2.setTotalWidth(new float[]{200, 100, 200, 200, 300});
subTable2.setLockedWidth(true);
subTable2.addCell("test 1");
subTable2.addCell("test 2");
subTable2.addCell("test 3");
subTable2.addCell("test 4");
subTable2.addCell("test 5");
PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(subTable2);
mainTable.addCell(cell2);
```

You are using the `AddElement()` method. That works too, but you need to set the padding to `0`:

```
PdfPTable subTable3 = new PdfPTable(5);
subTable3.setTotalWidth(new float[]{200, 200, 100, 200, 300});
subTable3.setLockedWidth(true);
subTable3.addCell("test 1");
subTable3.addCell("test 2");
subTable3.addCell("test 3");
subTable3.addCell("test 4");
subTable3.addCell("test 5");
PdfPCell cell3 = new PdfPCell();
cell3.setPadding(0);
cell3.addElement(subTable3);
mainTable.addCell(cell3);
```

Note that I defined the total width of the table as 1000 and that I made sure that the sum of all the column widths of the sub tables was identical to 1000. I also used the `setTotalWidths()` method because I'm passing absolute values (whereas you are passing relative values).

The final result looks like this: [cmp_nested_tables6.pdf](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/raw/master/cmpfiles/tables/cmp_nested_tables6.pdf)

[image]

As you can see, there is no white space on both sides.

Comment: great example, thanks. I'll try this out and make an update.